# How would I go about taking a user defined value on a webpage and substitute these values into a URL redirect?

Tags: php, html, api

I have a website page that's purely HTML (with some CSS elements). It contains user input (checkboxes and sliders), and the goal is to substitute the values that are defined by the visitor into an existing URL based API and redirect them to it when the form is submitted. I'm completely lost as to where to start.

Example: on button click, redirect the visitor to the website:checkbox1/slider1

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: can you show case your html code.